# How to set model value for mount_base64_uploader column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, base64, carrierwave

I tried to set my image column (base64 image) a value before i create the column but seems like it doesn't work.

I use this as my image base64 uploader
https://github.com/lebedev-yury/carrierwave-base64

This is my model

```
mount_base64_uploader :profile_image, PictureUploader
before_create :default_profile_image

private

  def default_profile_image
    self.profile_image = Base64.encode64(open("http://www.novotelbangkokploenchit.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/top-10-things-to-do-in-Bangkok.jpg").read).gsub("\n", '')
  end
```

So this my controller

```
user = User.new(user_params)
  if user.save
    user.remember_auth_token
    render json: user, status: 201 ,serializer: UserSerializer
  else
    render json: { errors: user.errors }, status: 422
  end
```

This is what i got from net work response

```
"user":{  
      "id":9,
      "email":"xxxxx@hotmail.com",
      "profile_image":{  
         "profile_image":{  
            "url":null
         }
      }
   }
```

So how can i make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use default value in your migration:
t.string :url, default: "myimage.jpg".

Comment: I can not use that because i plan to use cdn to contain all my images so if in the future i want to change file name it would be the problem.

Comment: So, can you set "hidden_field" in your form? <%= f.hidden_field :url, :value => "myimage.jpg" %>. Or in your controller after user = User.new(user_params): user.url = "myimage.jpg".

Comment: in controller: if user.url != ""